# VIIRS data unavailable in 2022

Tags: viirs

I am working with the nighttime data in the ImagineCollection NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG

The last observation available is for 2022-06 but the dataset provider has data available up to 2022-08. Is this data not available anymore?

Comment: If you referring to `Google Earth Engine` then some monthly images are unavailable (not only for 2022), at least for certain areas in the world. I wanted to download monthly images for few areas for the whole available period and I noticed that few images were full of null values. I don't know why though.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I want to believe that it's just a Google Earth thing and that the datasets get updated every certain period (like 6 month or something like that), because when you browse the VIIRS on the NOAA website, data gets updated daily. Let me know if you heard anything about possible solutions to the problem. https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/maps/VIIRS_DNB_nighttime_imagery/

Comment: Hi tocayo @DiegoJara. This seems to be a problem with GGE, indeed. I do not have a reason why they are not updating this but I am about to embark in using the NASA's Black Marble API to access this data... It is way more demanding for they have the data daily.